# Hue support for Azure Active Directory using OAuth

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, active-directory, hue

Is there a way to authorize access to Hue portal via an Azure Active Directory using OAuth? Does Hue provide the same by some configuration changes, if not, then how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hue has a [OAuth backend](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L286), so it might be supported (not sure if some tweaks are needed).